# OpenDayLight controller doesn't show Open vSwitch

Tags: raspberry-pi3, sdn, opendaylight, openflow, openvswitch

Recently i have been working with Open vSwitch on a Raspberry Pi, currently it has this configuration ([Open vSwitch configuration](https://i.stack.imgur.com/3wi5c.png)) and the controller list looks like this ([Controller list](https://i.stack.imgur.com/E7yxa.png)). My OpenFlow is on 192.168.0.16, and i have tried with the port 6633 and 6640, with no success. I had installed the following features there:

***feature:install odl-restconf odl-l2switch-switch odl-dluxapps-applications***

For ODL am using (karaf -0.8.1) and for ovs am using (Open vSwitch 2.12.90).

Here some captures of the
[OpenDayLight Nodes](https://i.stack.imgur.com/BbSHX.png)

Does anyone knows how can i show the open vswitch on this openflow? Or may be tell me what am doing wrong?

Answer (score 1):

Thanks for the reply!!!

I fixed it with the following command:

ovs-vsctl set bridge *your-switch-name* protocols=OpenFlow10

Answer (score 0):

the ovs-vsctl show output says "is_connected: true" and it's connected to
192.168.0.16. You said that was the address for your "OpenFlow" which I
don't understand. You want to set the controller address for OVS to point
to the OpenDaylight controller ip address on port 6633 or 6653. 6640 is for
OVSDB. I've never used the GUI method to check for nodes, but you can also
get a list of nodes that the controller knows about with a REST call like:

```
curl -u admin:admin http://<ODL IP ADDRESS>:8181/restconf/operational/opendaylight-inventory:nodes
```

if there are nodes listed in that output, then you have some problem with
OVS connecting. you can look in the karaf.log file for any clues.

Comment: Thanks dude, maybe i didn't expressed it well (am new on this). I fixed with the following command:

ovs-vsctl set bridge <your-switch-name> protocols=OpenFlow10